# Unity Baked Global Illumination Dyamic Objects Are Dark (even with light probes) (URP)

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, lighting

I use URP and baked directional light.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir1S2.jpg)

Edit: I of course already baked a lightmap. The problem is dynamic objects aren't enlighten by directional light(on baked mode).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I have no idea what lightning settings you have. Begin with this course and you should get most answer you'll need [https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-lighting-and-rendering](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-lighting-and-rendering)

Answer (score -2):

First save your scene. Then Open Window -> Rendering -> Lighting. Check the Auto-generate checkbox and give it a couple of minutes and see if your problem resolves.

Note: This may take several minutes depending upon your project size and your PC's CPU and Memory. If your system hangs for some time, leave it as it is and after the process completes, your PC becomes normal (my PC took (hangs) for about 20 minutes) and your problem will also solved.

Comment: I already baked ligting. I know how to bake a lightmap and what is a lightmap. I am asking that how to get dynamic objects effected from baked global llumination

Comment: @Mert: Sorry I'm a beginner. Does this help you? https://forum.unity.com/threads/any-runtime-dynamic-baking-options-or-are-any-coming.821676/

Comment: I found out that there is a thing called "light probe proxy volume" but it isn't supported by Universal Render Pipeline. Instead, I added another light and set it to realtime and I set it's culling mask to only one layer and gave that layer to dynamic objects. This way only the dynamic objects were enlighten by the realtime light and the whole scene was enlighten by a baked light so the performance didn't drop on mobile due to realtime light. But this technique has some limitations for example, the dynamic object is still bright even under a object's shadow.Now i'm going to++

Comment: read the thread you shared to find a better way, thanks for helping